# Minimum permission level to create list workflows

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, permissions

We have a user who needs to be able to create some SP Designer 2013 work flows on a list. For various reasons it would be better if this user did not have full control of the list. We found [this thread](https://community.nintex.com/thread/3041) that seems to say that Design permission is what the user needs, but giving the user Design privilege results in an error **You do not have permission to open this web site in SharePoint Designer**.

Also found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301820/minimum-permission-required-to-publish-a-workflow-using-sharepoint-designer) and several others that are similar about setting the security on the hidden workflows library through designer. Those posts are fairly old and either it has changed or we don't have permissions to set security on the workflows library.

We've looked through the various permissions levels when creating a new level and can't figure out if there is a way that doesn't include Full Control.

Comment: Did you give the user Design privilege to the entire site or just the list?  They probably need it for the entire site.

Comment: Just the list. I'll try with the site and see what happens.

Comment: Yup. That was it. Thanks. If you put it as an answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Users cannot open a site in Designer unless they have Designer or Full Control permissions to the entire site.

Comment: This is ambiguous. The SharePoint terminology uses Web or Site Collection. Which one did you mean?

Comment: SharePoint Designer uses the terminology "site" when you need to open a Web.