# Prevent users from creating poorly designed workflows

Tags: 2013, workflow, sharepoint-on-prem

Is there any resource throttling for preventing or terminating workflows that are poorly designed? There are users that are creating workflows that never end. Under quotas and templates, there is a limit for maximum usage, but that is for custom code solutions. This is in an on-premise SharePoint 2013 farm

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like if workflow proposals went through IT, they could at least review or test them to ensure they are not endless?  (Of course, I realise this is in an ideal world and may not be possible in reality!).

In case you can [reign in the user creation of workflows](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163851/minimum-permission-level-to-create-list-workflows) then this post will be of use to you - you would need to modify the permissions that users have in SharePoint site collections, Lists and Libraries.  A good security structure in a site is a good thing in itself.

Where I work no users have the option to create workflows, they also would not know how to create them well, though I work in a smaller organisation (120 people, of whom about a quarter use SharePoint).  In a larger organisation I still feel you would be better off restricting who can create workflows.  If users need to edit List or Document Library content, give them 'Contribute' permissions (from the OOTB user groups).

Train users in workflow creation or at least restrict membership of the 'Full Control' or 'Designer' group to users who have some competence with workflows.

Comment: We have 6000 users.  Designer is deactivated in our environment and turned on only when needed by the Admin.  All workflows are created by the Development team.